# Creating Framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I'm trying to create an iOS Framework (or a static library) for our customers to use.  I'd like to create a Framework using the Framework tool found here: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

It works really well but our Framework/static library has references to other static libs that we'd like to include in our Framework.  Basically we want to drag and drop 1 file into our customers' project, and they'll be able to use everything very easily.

Without sending them our Framework/static lib and all of the static libs we reference, is there any way to include this in our Framework?  Also, how can we handle duplicates in case our customers reference the same libraries?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if there's an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no way to include this...we have to send them copies of the static libs or have them include their own